# require_once can't load existing file on Windows 10 (works on Linux)

Tags: php, windows, psr-4

There is a mysterious problem with our autoloader:

```
function psr4_default_autoload( $class )
{
    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'basefolder\\';

    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = SOURCE_DIR . '/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen( $prefix );
    if ( strncmp( $prefix, $class, $len ) !== 0 ) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr( $class, $len );

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace( '\\', '/', $relative_class ) . '.php';

    if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
        require_once $file;
    }
}
```

`SOURCE_DIR`is an absolute path. Otherwise it's the original psr4 autoloader example: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md

This autoloader works on my Linux PC and on our server. However, on Windows `file_exists( $file )` returns true, but `require_once $file;` won't work. If we echo `$file` it returns exactly the file we want to load and the file also exists exactly there.

The error message is:

> Fatal error: Class 'basedir\DatabaseAbstraction\AEntity' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\classes\DatabaseAbstraction\Entity\UserLogin.php on line 14

That line is: `class UserLogin extends AEntity`. Context:

```
namespace basedir\DatabaseAbstraction\Entity;


use basedir\DatabaseAbstraction\AEntity;

class UserLogin extends AEntity
```

any ideas?

Comment: For now I'll keep my answer because you'd have faced the issue anyway I believe... Regarding your edit, what is the content of `$file` when the error is triggered ?

Comment: everything is fine with `$file`. There was a php missing in `<?php` ...

Comment: at least you have something working now. Might be good to add checks for this though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Windows directory separators are "\" while Linux's is "/"; you should use the "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR" keyword to represent the character used to create paths. It is determined at runtime, depending on the current OS.

In your case that would give:

```
$base_dir = SOURCE_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
[...]
$file = $base_dir . str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $relative_class ) . '.php'; // assuming your $base_dir follows the same logic
```

You'll also have to rework the SOURCE_DIR accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve it. I edited my question. The autoloader worked for a class but doesn't work for the class that it extends.

Comment: @Jaime: which Windows version? Which PHP version? I'd be interested in that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

The file AEntity.php started with `<?` instead of `<?php`. That's why the file wasn't loaded on that windows computer.

I go crying now.

Comment: Short tags are a configuration option in php.ini. It's probably set different between the two computers. I recommend to always use `<?php` regardless of the setting